# c# read a text file, but just save a specific line in an array

Tags: c#, arrays, replace, readfile, streamreader

I have a textfile with some data in it with this style:
ID, Box1, Box2, Box3, Box4, Box5, Box6, Box7, Box8, Box9, Box10, Box11, Box12, Box13, Box14

The Id is always 7 digits long. and in the other fields will stand a time or can also be null.
Now i have to check if an ID is already existing. If the Id is existing i want to save this line int an array seperated by the",", to do then changes to the times or to add one. And after this array should be rewritten in the textfile.

How to do it??

Comment: Could you share you code?

Comment: I have no Code for this special function. And the other code is 650 rows long but will not help for this function i think

Comment: `check if an ID is already existing` where have  to check? Can you share the code which opens the text file and reads the line? Are you splitting the line by `,` ?

Comment: Some sample data would be helpful - the data you've shown has only one ID, but it sounds like there are more. Is this a sample *line* from the file, or is the whole file a bunch of comma-separated values with no line breaks?. Also, Where does the existing ID come from? It would be nice if you showed what you've tried so far so we can see what's wrong and have something to build on.

Comment: I have no function at the moment that is reading the file. That was also the question what would be the best to do that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a little unclear exactly what you're looking for, but it sounds like you have a file where every line starts with an ID, followed by a comma-separated list of values; and the goal is to see if a specific ID exists, and if it does, save the values associated with it to an array.

One way to do this is to read the file line by line, and for each line, split it on the `,` separator and compare the first item (at index `0`) to the ID we're searching for. If it's a match, return the split values array.

```
public string[] GetLineWithID(string id, string filePath)
{
    if (id == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("id cannot be null.");
    if (filePath == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("filePath cannot be null.");
    if (!File.Exists(filePath)) throw new FileNotFoundException(filePath);
    
    foreach(var line in File.ReadLines(filePath))
    {
        var lineParts = line.Split(',');
        if (lineParts[0] == id) return lineParts; // Returns the CSV line as an array
    }
    
    return null;                
}
```